# regex to replace date part

Tags: regex, sed

I have a file like
A_B_C_D_E_F_20180904_0038849_SUPER03.txt

I want to extract just A_B_C_D_E_F.txt

My try

```
echo A_B_C_D_E_F_20180904_0038849_SUPER03.txt |sed -e 's/'_[0-9]{8}_.*'/'*.txt'/g'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things need to change:

- You shouldn't run sed with the `-e` option, which is meant to run sed scripts
- You don't need the single quotes within sed
- You should use `\{` and `\}` to denote quantifiers in sed's regex syntax
- You don't need a wildcard `*` in your replacement text

With the above changes, this would work to produce `A_B_C_D_E_F.txt`:

```
echo A_B_C_D_E_F_20180904_0038849_SUPER03.txt |sed 's/_[0-9]\{8\}_.*/.txt/'
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
echo A_B_C_D_E_F_20180904_0038849_SUPER03.txt \
  |sed -e 's/_[0-9]\{8\}_[0-9]\{7\}_[A-Z0-9]*//g'
```

where:

`_[0-9]\{8\}` - match `_20180904`

`_[0-9]\{7\}` - match `_0038849`

`_[a-zA-Z0-9]*` - match `_SUPER03`

As result you get: `A_B_C_D_E_F.txt`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/_[0-9][^.]*//' file
```

Delete the first occurrence of an underscore followed by an integer up until a period.

Answer (score 1):

If your filename is assigned to variable, and your shell is `bash`, you could avoid using `sed` and use directly parameter expansion:

```
v="A_B_C_D_E_F_20180904_0038849_SUPER03.txt"
echo "${v%_*_*_*}.${v#*.}"
A_B_C_D_E_F.txt
```

`bash` operators `%` and `#` remove respectively the matching suffix or prefix pattern.

Comment: This is truly cool and elegant solution as we go more into fancy programming languages we forget good old simple things :).Thanks oliv